# How to describe data using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, coding-style

I have a Python program in which I keeps most of the data in dictionaries, mostly because it is easy for me to understand the logic and data flow.

The drawback of this solution is slow computation. I want to rewrite the software using NumPy library.
For example I have an object:

`point = {"x": 0.323441, "y": 0.982531, "r": 12, "r": 42, "b": 241}`

and I can rewrite it as:

`np.array([0.323441, 0.982531, 12, 42, 241])`

This example is quite obvious but I'm afraid that in case of more complicated data I will have problem to get an idea what does the data mean.

What are the best practices to describe data in NumPy?

Comment: I would suggest using a Pandas DataFrame, whose underlying data are held in numpy arrays, but give much more readable tables. In your example, you'd have a column for each (and I think you can pass a dictionary to a pandas DataFrame constructor

Comment: Within NumPy itself, you also have [structured arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html), which allow you to give names to different "fields" of the data. But, as suggested, Pandas is a much more common choice (there is also [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org) for high-dimensional labelled data).

Comment: It's not only what point is, but more whether you have many other points that are similarly described. For numpy and pandas, the primary question is whether your data is well described by "columns" where the values in each column: 1) are the same type, and a type that numpy supports (and not `object`); 2) refer to the same concept but with different values; 3+) other things that I can't think of now. That is, instead of having `point`s, you'll have `points_xy = np.zeros((1000, 2))` and `points_rgb = np.zeros((1000,3))` where variable names describe what it is (as is usual in Python).

Answer (score 2):

Using your example data:

Just spotted double-use of the "r" variable, which your dictionary wouldn't allow either

```
d = pd.DataFrame({"x": 0.323441, "y": 0.982531, "r": 12, "r_": 42, "b": 241}, index=[1])
```

result:

```
          x         y   r  r_    b
1  0.323441  0.982531  12  42  241
```

Comment: 1) Do I always need to provide index explicitly?
2) Are operations on Pandas DataFrame as fast as on NumPy arrays?

Comment: 1) you don't if the dictionary values are vectors - in your case they are scalars so Pandas gives an error. I think it would work for `range(len(data))` if needed.
2) pretty much, if speed does become an issue, you can always access the underlying data with a call to `d.values` that gives you a numpy array. Pandas, and the DataFrame object have lots of methods for common needs though